# Github Copilot running in single file mode?

Tags: neovim, github-copilot, nvim-lspconfig

I'm running Github copilot on neovim. When I run `:LspInfo`, I see the following. Is this expected, or a configuration issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, `copilot.vim` currently only supports single file mode.

You can see this for yourself in the copilot.vim github repository. In the lua file there is no reference to the `root_dir` field in the lsp start call.